# Changing resource folder directory from Target classes to source in Java

Tags: java, file, properties-file

I am trying to read a property file from `src/main/resources` in my Java web application.
The problem is when i tried to load the file using below code

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

Its trying to fetch file form target classes ad getting Exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\PL90169\Java%20Projects\MKPFileUploadService\target\classes\config.properties".

How to change file reading directory from target to source folder instead of target.
Attached project structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUNz.png)

Comment: @Leviand using utility class  helped me to read property,but i am trying to read URL(ex: C:\Users\amit\Upload Folder Location), property value from prop.getProperty(property); is without \ i.e (C:UsersamitUpload Folder Location) URL.How to read URL property from property file

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you building an utility class, so you can easly load all properties that you need, something like:

```
public static String getPropertyValue(String property) throws IOException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "config.properties";
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    return prop.getProperty(property);
}
```

So if in your `config.properties` file you put something like

```
exampleValue=hello
```

when you call `getPropertyValue("exampleValue")` you will get `hello`

Comment: It helped me to read property,but i am trying to read URL(ex: C:\Users\amit\Upload Folder Location), property value from prop.getProperty(property); is without \ i.e (C:UsersamitUpload Folder Location) URL.How to read URL property from property file

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
while (true) {
  int readCount = inputStream.read(buffer);
  if (readCount < 0) break;
  bOut.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}

String configContent = bOut.toString("UTF-8");
```